# How can I make a player to play Guessing game again?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int guess;


srand(time(NULL));

int number=rand()%10+1;

do
{
    cout<<"Welcome to the number guessing game!"<<endl;
    cout<<"Guess a number between 1 and 10"<<endl;
    cin>>guess;

    if(guess<number)
        cout<<"Your guess is less than the number "<<endl;
    else if(guess>number)
        cout<<"Your guess is greater than the number "<<endl;

    if(guess==number)
        cout<<"Congratulation! You guess the number!!"<<endl;

}
while(guess!=number);




system("PAUSE");
return 0;
 }
```

Hello. This was a project that my C++ professor assigned to me. I was able to come up with the algorithm about how this program functions but I am stuck at the point where you make a user play this game as many time as he/she likes. I am assuming if I have to do some nested do...while statement inside the main do...while ...and I am just not sure. And P.S, when you make a user input "y" or "n" as the answer, you have to make that part char type integer right?

Comment: "*[...] make a user play this game as many time as he/she **doesn't** like*" Whaaa ?

Comment: *I have to do some nested do...while statement inside the main do...while:* Yes

Comment: oh! I am sorry ...typo perhaps...thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could put this all in another do while loop. Inside it, first execute this loop, and then ask the user to input either 'y' or 'n' (or whatever Identifiers you like) and store it into a char variable.  Then just check if what they entered is equal to 'y' in the while part of the outer loop.

Note that if the enter 'yes' with this approach the game would stop, so it is possible you might want to use a sting variable instead and check for more possible inputs.